# In chef how is it possible to generate a variable from a recipe and another recipe to use that variable?

Tags: chef-recipe

I want a recipe which will **run on a client**  to create a variable which will store the FQDN of the client  and another recipe which will **run on another server** to use that variable .how is that possible in chef.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for service discovery, Chef might not be the best tool for this job. However, if your client is running Chef, its FQDN is already stored in Chef server. You can [pull it in various ways](https://docs.chef.io/chef_search.html). For example

```
client_node = search(:node, "recipes:client_cookbook::client_recipe")
```

Then you can access client's FQDN from the node mash - `client_node["fqdn"]`.